# Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6 in SQL Azure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I regularly experience the above error when creating connections to `Azure` SQL databases. I've implemented `ReliableSqlConnection` with retry logic in attempt to avoid this issue but it has been to no avail. Following is an example error stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6. 
System.InvalidOperationException: Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6. 
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ReliableSqlConnection.<Open>b__1()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ReliableSqlConnection.<Open>b__0()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ReliableSqlConnection.Open(RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
```

This issue happens when creating a new database in an elastic pool. The SQL command text is execute in the following method:

```
public void ExecuteCommandText(string commandText)
    {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(commandText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandText));

        List<string> commandSteps = SplitCommandText(commandText);

        using (var sqlConnection = CreateConnection())
        {
            foreach (string commandStep in commandSteps)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = commandStep;
                    command.CommandTimeout = _commandTimeout;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where:

```
private ReliableSqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string is not defined.");

        ReliableSqlConnection sqlConnection = new ReliableSqlConnection(ConnectionString, _retryPolicy, _retryPolicy);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        return sqlConnection;
    }
```

And:

```
var retryStrategy = new ExponentialBackoff(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
_retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
```

The connection string is of the format:

```
$"Server=tcp:{serverName},1433;Data Source={serverName};Persist Security Info=False;User ID='{user}';Password='{password}';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=90;"
```

Also, I've checked the `eDTU` usage on my elastic pool:

[Elastic pool eDTU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwj4D.png)

The first spike is from creating 1 database in the pool, the second is for 2, the third is for 3 and the fourth is for creating 4 databases concurrently. The elastic pool service tier is Standard 100.

Comment: Can you share the code where this error is thrown, the connection string you're using (sans sensitive details), and review your DTU graph of your Azure SQL database (are you hitting DTU limits)?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: So you see connection issues when you're adding a database to the pool?

Comment: Yes, the process creates a new database in the pool and then creates the schema.

Comment: Are your connection issues to the newly created database or the other databases in the pool?

Comment: Both, I think. The issues are transient. I believe I've found a workaround; rather than creating and then updating a database directly in the pool, I've modified the process to create a standalone database outside of the pool, create the schema and then move the database into the pool. This appears to be a more robust approach and the impact on the pool resource usage is negligible.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue - the same "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6" error when creating a new DB on an Elastic Pool. Did you get any further with it?  Is it caused by trying to use the DB **too soon** after creating it perhaps?

Comment: FYI, if using .Net 4.6.1+ then you can add `ConnectRetryCount=8;ConnectRetryInterval=2` to your connection string [see documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/dn632678.aspx)

Comment: As per my comment above, my workaround was to create the database outside the elastic pool and move it into the pool afterwards. I've wrapped everything in retry logic as well. It seems to be working robustly now.

Comment: @ASH Fair enough, am hoping to find a proper explanation and a fix rather than having to code around it. Thanks.

Comment: @OffHeGoes Did you ever find a proper explanation for this issue?

Comment: @ASH Nope, and I am still seeing this occur regularly.

Comment: Is this an Azure web app or virtual machine? If its the former, for your connection strings, are you setting them in Azure app settings as far as what type of connection string are they? Example: MySQL, Server Server, SQL Database, Document DB, etc? For Azure SQL, they should be set to "Custom".

Comment: are all of you Azure SQL databases the same version?

Answer (score 5):

This is one of Azure SQL transient error. A lot of info is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440719(v=pandp.60).aspx. Seem the same error when trying to do backups via code. In those cases I drop and re-initiate.

Comment: I would go ahead and contact their support by opening a ticket; they are very helpful and knowledgeable.